# How to customise Html Editor control of Ajax in asp.net using VB?

Tags: asp.net

I want to change the default view of Html Editor in asp.net using language as vb but i don't have any idea how to do it. Can any one tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all that you can do to change the default view of this extender is in css and markup properties, it actually has almost nothing to do with vb.net.
Look at the this site for more info:
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/htmleditor/htmleditor.aspx

There are some samples but more important, info about what look and feel you can modify 
eg.

```
.CustomEditorStyle .ajax__htmleditor_editor_toptoolbar {
        background-color:#F0F0F0; padding: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
}
```

That means that the extender look for special css clases.
And you can modify those to change l&f.

Hope this help you.

Comment: The answer that i was looking about is to add and remove top toolbar buttons, I found the answer on this site [link]http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/editor-control-custom